# What is meant by 'kala sarpa'?

Tags: terminology

Some scriptures contain the word `kala sarpa`. It is treated as an inauspicious thing.

**What exactly is kala sarpa**?

Comment: Are u talking abt the Kala Sarpa dosha of astrology?

Comment: No, just kala sarpa... Saw in some Purana slokhas... Will try to put such slokha... @Rickross

Comment: kala sarpa is metaphorical. Which means serpant like time will bite you . Ultimately time spares no one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kāla-sarpa means Yamarāja or in general, in a poetic-sense - 'the devouring nature of Time'.

---

Kāla-sarpa literally translates as the 'serpent of time' or 'serpent of death'.

And Time, Death and its Lordship is most commonly associated with - Yamarāja.

One may ask references for the above assertion.

> [Chapter 138](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083368.html), Agni Purāṇa
>
> यमोऽसि यमाराजोऽसि कालरूपोऽसि धर्मराट् ।
>
> > 11. You are Yama (god of death). You are the sovereign over the dead (Yamarāja). You are of the form of time. You are the reign of
> >     righteousness.
>
> English Translation by N. Gangadharan

---

Two references for 'Kāla-sarpa' from the Skanda Purāṇa are:-

- #### Reference 1:

> [Chapter 67](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423806.html) -  Uttarārdha - Kāśī-khaṇḍa
>
> [Verse 4.2.17.69](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc774686.html)
>
> शंखचूडेश्वरश्चैष शंखचूडप्रतिष्ठितः ।
>  यस्य संदर्शनात्पुंसां न भयं
> **कालसर्प**जम् ॥ ६९ ॥
>
> > 169. This is Śaṅkhacūḍeśvara installed by Śaṅkhacūḍa. The visit to this Lord removes the fear arising from **Kālasarpa (Black Serpent, i.e.
> >      god of Death).**

- #### Reference 2:

> [Chapter 100](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423839.html) -  Uttarārdha - Kāśī-khaṇḍa
>
> [Verse 4.2.50.3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc778332.html)
>
> निराशाः पितरस्तस्य तस्मिन्नेव दिनेऽभवन् ।
>  स दष्टः **कालसर्पेण** स
> दृष्टो मृत्युना स्फुटम् ॥ ३ ॥
>  स मुष्टस्तत्र दिवसे विश्वेशो यत्र नेक्षितः ।
>
> > 3. ... The Pitṛs become disappointed on the very same day. **He is indeed bitten by the serpent of Kāla - **Kāla-sarpa (death, time)**.
> >    He is seen by death to be sure**....
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

---

So, Kāla-sarpa is an allusion to:

- The Lord of Death: Yamarāja.

or

- The general nature of Time (which devours everyone with its 'deadly fangs' of death).