# Why Maa Lakshmi says that neither Lord Brahma nor Lord Vishnu only Lord Shiva commands her to move from one place to another.?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, mahabharata

According to Mahabharata.:

> *“śrīruvāca
> na mā̃ virōcanō vēda nāyaṁ vairōcanō baliḥ.
> āhurmā̃ duḥsahētyēvaṁ vidhitsēti ca mā̃ viduḥ.|7
> bhūtirlakṣmīti māmāhuḥ śrīrityēvaṁ ca vāsava.
> tvaṁ mā̃ śakra na jānīṣē sarvē dēvā na mā̃ viduḥ|” (MBH 12:225:7-8)*
>
> *“Sree said, ‘Virochana did not know me. This Bali also that is the son of Virochana knows me not. The learned called me by the name of Duhshaha. Some knew me by the name of Vidhitsa. I have other names also, O Vasava! They are **Bhuti, Lakshmi, and Sree.** Thou knowest me not, O Sakra, nor doth any one among the deities know me”.*

When Indra asks her the reason behind her deserting Bali and asks if due to his(Indra's) acts or due to Bali’s any act, Sree says that it is nobody’s acts that can invite her or make her desert someone. She functions at the commands of Kala (mahakala).

> *“śrīruvāca
> nō dhātā na vidhātā mā̃ vidadhāti kathañcana.
> kālastu śakra paryāgānmainaṁ śakrāvamanyathāḥ|” (MBH 12:225:10)*
>
> ***“Sree said, ‘Neither the Creator(Brahma) nor the Ordainer(Vishnu) rules me. It is Kala(Shiva) that moves me from one place to another.** Do not, O Sakra, disregard Bali."*

Sree clearly says that neither the creator (dhata i.e., Brahma) nor the ordainer (vidhata i.e., Vishnu) rule her. She moves from one place to another at the command of Mahakala (Shiva).

Go to [here](http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/2014/11/the-unfading-glory-of-mahakala.html) for more info.

So my question is why is that.?

**Edit.:**

I saw many people are saying that why **kaala** is being translated to **shiva** and some are saying **purusha suktam** says this and that. To clear all these confusions let me put some verses in this question only, so that I think it will make this question more clearer.

.Shvetashvatara Upanishad makes this point very clear.

> *“sa viśvakṛd viśvavidātmayōnirjñaḥ **kālakālō** guṇī sarvavid yaḥ |
> pradhānakṣētrajñapatirguṇēśaḥ saṁsāramōkṣasthitibandhahētuḥ |” (Ṣvētāṣvatāra  Upaniṣad 6:16)
> “He (i.e., Rudra) makes all, he knows all, the self-caused, the knower, **the time of time (destroyer of time)**, who assumes qualities and knows everything, the master of nature and of man, the lord of the three qualities (guna), the cause of the bondage, the existence, and the liberation of the world”*

> *“sarvaanana shirogriivaH sarvabhuutaguhaashayaH |
> sarvavyaapii sa bhagavaa.nstasmaat.h sarvagataH shivaH |” (Svetaswatara Upanishad. 3:11)
> “**All faces are His faces; all heads, His heads; all necks, His necks. He dwells in the hearts of all beings. He is the all— pervading Bhagavan. Therefore He is omnipresent Shiva”**.*

Vedas say that Maheshwara is beyond the Vedas and is the highest Brahman as follows.

> *“yo vedaadau svaraH prokto vedaante cha pratishhThitaH
> tasya prakR^itiliinasya yaH paraH sa **maheshvaraH** ” (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.12.3.17)
> “That (being) who transcends (or is higher than) the syllable Om which is uttered at the commencement of the recital of the Vedas, which is well established in the Upanishads and which is dissolved in the primal cause during contemplation, is **Maheshwara**”.*

> “mahādēvaṁ paraṁ brahmā ṣabdabrahmātanumparaṁ |” (Shiva Purana 2:08:13)
> “That Mahadeva who is the supreme brahman is superior than the sabda-brahman”.

In the Uttara Khanda of Padma Purana (Shiva Gita).

> *“prāṇaḥ kālastathā mṛtyuramṛtaṁ bhūtamapyahama |
> bhavyaṁ bhaviṣyatkṛtsnaṁ ca viśvaṁ sarvātmakō’pyahama |” (Shiva Gita 6:26)
> “**I’m the Prana (life force), I’m the time, death, and eternity. I’m the past, present and future. I’m everything indeed!**”*

Taittiriya Aranyaka of Yajurveda for vamdeva shiva state as follows.

> *“vāmadēvāya namō jyēṣṭhāya namaḥ śrēṣṭhāya namō
> rudrāya namaḥ **kālāya namaḥ** kalavikaraṇāya namō |” (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.18.1)
> “Salutation to Vamadeva. Salutation to Jyestha (the Eldest, existing before creation). Salutation to Srestha (the most worthy and excellent). Salutation to Rudra. **Salutation to Kala**. **Salutation to Kalavikarana (He who causes changes in the evolution of the universe beginning with Prakriti)”**.*

Taittiriya Aranyaka of Yajurveda describes Supreme Brahman as follows.

> *“ṛtaṁ satyaṁ paraṁ brahma **puruṣaṁ** **kṛṣṇapiṅgalam** .
> ūrdhvarētaṁ virūpākśaṁ viśvarūpāya vai namō namaḥ |” (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.23.1)
> “Supreme Brahman, the Absolute Righteousness (rita) and Truth (satyam), is the **Purusha** **dark and tawny** in hue(ardhanareshwara), absolutely chaste (having semen raised up) and possessing uneven eyes (three eyed) . Salutations to Him alone who is the Soul of the universe, or whose form is the universe”*

In Mahabharata Mausala Parva when the time for the destruction of Yadava race (vrishni race) had come, then **Lord Shiva as the Mahakala in his embodied (saguna) form started roaming in the Dwaraka city to end their race** as stated below. Note the description of that embodied form – the dark and tawny **(“kr̥ṣṇa-pingalaṁ”)** form.

> *“vaiśampāyana uvāca
> ēvaṁ prayatamānānā̃ vṛṣṇīnāmandhakaiḥ saha.
> kālō gṛhāṇi sarvēṣā̃ paricakrāma nityaśaḥ |1
> karālō vikaṭō muṇḍaḥ puruṣaḥ kṛṣṇapiṅgalaḥ.
> gṛhāṇyāvēkṣya vṛṣṇīnā̃ nādṛśyata kvacitkvacit |2
> tamaghnanta mahēṣvāsāḥ śaraiḥ śatasahasraśaḥ.
> na cāśakyata vēddhũ sa sarvabhūtātyayastadā |” (MBH 16:2:1-3)
> “[Vaishampayana said:] While the Vrishnis and the Andhakas were thus endeavouring (to avoid the impending calamity), **the embodied form of Time (death) every day wandered about their houses. He looked like a man of terrible and fierce aspect. Of bald head, he was black and of tawny complexion**. Sometimes he was seen by the Vrishnis as he peered into their houses. The mighty bowmen among the Vrishnis shot hundreds and thousands of shafts at him, but none of these succeeded in piercing him, for he was none else than the Destroyer of all creatures”.*

Note that here the Mahakala who has been personified as death has been described as **“mundaḥ” (bald)** and **kṛṣṇapiṅgalaḥ (dark and tawny)**. We have already seen that kṛṣṇapiṅgalaḥ is an attribute of Bhagawan Shiva only. Now here we have another attribute described that is – he, the death god was bald. In fact Bhagawan Rudra appears as having matted locks of hair and also otherwise he appears as bald headed.  In this connection we have **Yajurveda itself hailing Rudra as having matted locks as well as who displays a bald head** as follows.

> *“nama kapardine cha vyuptakesaya cha |” (Yajurveda IV:5:5:d)
> “**Salutations to him who has a crown of hair and to him who has a shaved head**”.*

**Therefore now it is clear from above discussion that the Supreme Brahman described in Vedas a ‘Dark and tawny’ lord is the same bald headed Mahakala who appeared in the city of Dwaraka to put an end to their entire race.**

According to Mahabharata.:

> *“That Being whom, at the time of all thy battles, thou beheldest stalking in thy van, know, O son of Kunti, is no other than Rudra, that god of gods, otherwise called by the name of Kaparddin. **He is otherwise known by the name of Kala**" (MBH 12:342:138-140)*

According to Shiva maha puranam.:

> *“brahmovāca |
> yato vāco nivartaṃte aprāpya manasā saha
> yasmātsarvamidaṃ brahmaviṣṇurudreṃdrapūrvakam
> sahabhūteṃdriyaiḥ sarvaiḥ prathamaṃ saṃprasūyate
> eṣa devo mahādevaḥ sarvajño jagadīśvaraḥ
> ayaṃ tu parayā bhaktyā dṛśyate nā ‘nyathā kvacit |” (Shiva Purana 1:3:10-12)
> “[Brahma replied]: – that without grasping which speech turns back along with the mind, **from whom Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Indra, together with all elements (and creatures) and senses, at first spring forth; That lord, Mahadeva is the omniscient and Ishwara (lord) of the universe**. This Shankara can be grasped (or seen) through great devotion else he cannot be seen”.*

So it's clear from here that from shiva(kala) Brahmas', Vishnus' and Rudras' etc originates. So it can also be said that after pralaya they disappear in him only.

Shivpuran says.

> *“asādhāraṇakarmā cha sr̥ṣtyādikaraṇātpr̥thak |
> brahmāṇōpi ṣiraṣchhētā janakastasya tatsutaḥ |121
> janakastanayaṣchāpi viṣṇōrapi niyāmakaḥ |
> bōdhakaṣcha tayōrnityamanugrahakaraḥ |” (Shiva Purana 7:02:31:121-122)
> “His (Shiva’s) works are said to be uncanny because he (alone) carries out creation, preservation and destruction. He is the one who cut brahma’s head. He is the father of Brahma as well as his son. Similarly, He is the father of Vishnu as well as his son and he is also the controller of Vishnu. He confers knowledge on these two – Brahma and Vishnu and always showers his grace (upon them)”.*

Which is also in sync with vedas.

> *“sá evá sáṃ bhúvanāny ā́bharat sá evá sáṃ bhúvanāni páry ait
> pitā́ sánn abhavat putrá eṣāṃ tásmād vái nā́nyát páram asti téjaḥ |” (Atharva Veda 19:53:4)
> “He surely did bring hither all the beings (worlds), he surely did encompass all the beings (worlds). **Being their father, he became their son**; there is, verily, no other force, higher than he”.*

As for Purusha Shukran.:

Purusha Sukta appeared first in Rig Veda 10.90. Narayana Maharshi was the 'Mantra Drashta'(seer) of the hymn. This Narayana Maharshi was later incarnated as Devaki putra Sri Krishna during Dwaparayuga. His counterpart Nara Maharshi was born as 'Arjuna'. By the grace of Lord Shiva, Narayana Mahrshi got the divine vision of Purusha. He was the first Human Rishi to realise the universal oneness and oneness of Atman in all beings. This non-dual knowledge made Narayana Rishi merge with Lord Shiva. Those who know Purusha will become, verily, like Purusha, the self of all beings.

Sathapatha Brahmana of Shukla yajurveda describes how Narayana Rishi became one with Purusha.

> *"puruṣo ha nārāyaṇo'kāmayata atitiṣṭheyaṃ sarvāṇi bhūtānyahamevedaṃ sarvaṃ syāmiti sa etam puruṣamedham pañcarātram yajñakratumapaśyattamāharattenāyajata teneṣṭvātyatiṣṭhatsarvāṇi bhūtānīdaṃ sarvamabhavadatitiṣṭhati sarvāṇi bhūtānīdaṃ sarvam bhavati ya evam vidvānpuruṣamedhena yajate yo vaitadevam veda" ( Sathapatha Brahmana 13:6:1:1)*

Meaning:

> *"Purusha Narayana desired, 'Would that I overpassed all beings ! would that I alone were everything- here (this universe) !' He beheld this 'five days' sacrificial performance, the Purushamedha and took it and performed offering therewith ; and having performed offering therewith, he overpassed all beings, and became everything here. And, verily, he who, knowing this, performs the Purushamedha, or who even knows this, overpasses all beings, and becomes everything here."*

In Mahabharata, Anushasana parva Bishma pitamaha says to Yudhistira:

> *Rudra bhakthya thu krishnena jagat vyaptham mahathmana,
> Tham prasadhya thadha devam bhadaryam kila bharatha.*
>
> *Arthath priya harathwam cha sarva lokeshu vai yadhaa,
> Prapthavaaneva rajendra suvarnaakshan maheswaraath.*
>
> *"The Krishna, due to his devotion to Supreme Lord Rudra, Has spread all over the universe, Oh Bharatha, Oh king of kings, After making Lord Shiva pleased by his penance in Bhadrinath, He has attained the state of being more dear, Than all the worlds and all aspects of knowledge."*

In Mahabaratha, Lord Shiva says :

> *satyaśaucārjava tyāgais tapasā niyamena ca
> kṣāntyā bhaktyā ca dhṛtyā ca buddhyā ca vacasā tathā ( Mh Bhar 10.7.60)*

> *yathāvad aham ārāddhaḥ kṛṣṇenākliṣṭakarmaṇā
> tasmād iṣṭatamaḥ kṛṣṇād anyo mama na vidyate ( Mh Bhar 10.07.61)*

Meaning:

> *"With truth, purity, sincerity, resignation, ascetic austerities, vows, forgiveness, devotion, patience, thought, and word, I have been duly adored by Krishna of pure deeds. For this there is none dearer to me than Krishna".*

Purusha Sukta :

> *sahasraśīrṣā puruṣaḥ sahasrākṣaḥ sahasrapāt |*
> *sabhūmiṃ viśvato vṛtvātyatiṣṭhad daśāṅghulam ||*
> *sahasra - Thousands; ( Thousand implies uncountable )*
> *śīrṣā - of heads has;*
> *puruṣaḥ - the great being.*
> *sahasra -Thousands of*
> *aksha - eyes has he,*
> *sahasrapāt - and thousands of legs.*
> *sa - He*
> *vṛtvā - manifests*
> *bhūmiṃ - the world.*
> *ātyatiṣṭhat - e stands beyond*
> *daśāṅghulam - the count of ten fingers.*

Meaning:

> *A thousand heads hath Puruṣa, a thousand eyes, a thousand feet.*
> *On every side pervading earth he fills a space ten fingers wide.*

**The Taittirya Aranyaka(10:24:1) of Yajur Veda clearly says Lord Rudra is 'Veda Purusha' (purusho vai rudrah) Kaushitaki Brahmana (6:1:13) of Rig Veda calls Lord Rudra as **"sahasrakha sahasrapat"**. ( tata.udatiṣṭhat.sahasra.akṣaḥ.sahasra.pāt).** The same thing is confirmed in Svetasvatara Upanishad.

> *viśvataś cakṣur uta viśvato-mukho*
> *viśvato-bāhur uta viśvatas-pāt*
> *saṃ6 bāhubhyāṃ dhamati sampatatrair*
> *dyāv-ābhūmī janayan deva ekaḥ ( Sv Up III-3)*
> *"His eyes are everywhere, His faces everywhere, His arms everywhere, everywhere His feet. He it is who endows men with arms, birds with feet and wings and men likewise with feet. Having produced heaven and earth, this God (deva ekaḥ) remains as their non—dual manifestation.*

For more info visit [here](http://hara-hara-mahadev.blogspot.com/2010/07/purusha-suktam-hymn-to-lord-rudra-also.html?m=1).

According to purusha shuktam of yajurveda.:

> *"**Hri** and **Lakshmi(Sri)** are thy (Purusha Rudra's) wives: each side of thee are **Day** and **Night**."*

According to Uma Samhita and Shiva Puran :

> *"Satī and Pārvatī are Umā's direct incarnations (Rudranī). The first primordial Śakti of Śiva the great Brahman, who is called Umā, is the great mother of the three worlds. Her two incarnations — Satī and Haimavatī, have been heard, O intelligent Sūta. Please mention Her other incarnations **(Mahākālikā; Mahālakṣmī; Mahāsarasvatī)** too. (Umā Saṁhitā: 45:3-4)"*

> *"**Mahākālikā; Mahālakṣmī; Mahāsarasvatī are Umā's incarnation as warrior goddess**. According to Śiva Purāṇa, Bhavānī Umā is the source of these three forms Navārṇa Caṇḍikā of Devī Māhātmyam, hence both Aṣṭādaśabhujā **Mahālakṣmī (not to be confused with Viṣṇupatni Lakṣmī)** as well as Bhavānī Umā are identified with one another by Śiva Purāṇa. (Umā Saṁhitā: Chapter 45-48)"*

> **Mahalakshmi is another name Goddess Parvati. Who is wife of lord Shiva.
> Real name is Ambabai Mahalakshmi she is Goddess Parvati.
> Kollapur Ambabai Mahalakshmi its Shaktipeet of Goddess Sati / Parvati not a wife of vishnu. Even devi kamla (lakshmi) one of the 10 mahavidhyas is a form of devi uma** .

The Chamunda Mantra of Maa Kali/Durga.

> *"Om aim **hrim** srim Klim chamundaye viche"
> Om = lord shiva of creator and destroyer
> Aim = goddess saraswati of knowledge and wisdom
> Shreem = goddess lakshmi of wealth and luck
> **Hreem = goddess pravati of divine mother**
> Kleem = goddess maha kali of love and desire
> Chamundaye = The slayer of demons chand and mund
> Viche = shield us.*

So here we can see all these names belongs to maa durga/kali she is also called as "sri" and maa parvati as "hri".

So from above we can conclude that purusha Rudra's two wives are maa Parvati and maa Kali/Durga. One is day (Maa Parvati as she is calm and giving in nature) and other is night (Maa Kali who is angrier and fierce in nature).

Natsyashastra 3(86,87)

> *"let mothers such as Sarasvati, Dhriti, Medha, **Hri, Sri, Lakshmi** protect you and give you success."*

As you can see here sometimes, sri is only refered to maa durga and not maa Lakshmi and hri always to maa parvati.

Just like lord vishnu is called shrivatsa (the one with shree/lakshmi in his chest), lord shiva is also called as shrikantha (the one with shree/durga in his throat).

I still have so many verses left to add but I think this is enough otherwise it will get double in length because it is lengthy as it is.

So again my main question was why Maa Lakshmi only listens to Lord Mahakala is it because of him being the Supreme Brahman?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119614/discussion-on-question-by-savdy-why-maa-lakshmi-says-that-neither-lord-brahma-no).

Comment: There are nothing satvik, rajasik or tamasik of that sort about any Puranas. As all Puranas are said to be the body parts of Hari n leads to salvation. These are all interpolated verse by various sects. Even skanda puran says that vaishnava purans are tamsik n Shaiva purans are sattvik. So these are all just interpolated verse n if not than vedvyas himself has booked 1st class VIP ticket to hell. As one can't write something without reading or reciting it 1si. Period. .

Comment: I feel like this is just practical advice that wealth is not preordained by God and you should put time and effort in to get it.

Comment: @Anupakarana Abhibhaa yes, you can take it as a practical advice.And yes karma matters but mahabharata says that due to ignorance and under influence of kala people lost their ways.And sometimes who was born rich becomes poor n those who are poor becomes rich.When their time comes under influence of kala they starts doing ignorent things under ego. Like in case of ravan and yadavas.Which leads to their destruction.Same is said about bali who under influence of kala started doing bgnarant things that's why shree left him and went to indra.Ishwara Gita Says, Lord Shiva as Lord of all the Karmas.

Comment: Yes it's nt preordained bt I feel like the karmas of previous births also matters.And kala is said to be impartial to all.Shree is said to be fortune and chanchala (unstable) so wd hard work sometimes luck is also necessary.Otherwise there are so many ppl doing hard work but still erning handful nly while other with little work gets rich.Yes hard work pays but the fact is just HW is nt enough n luck is also a factor which cannot be ignored.Like Sometimes you can study everything but still can find question paper uncommon while other by limiting study only can find common questions in exams..

Comment: @Priyansh Jain when i revisited our convo i couldn't help but notice that u are saying the whole translation is invalid because on the claim that krishna is brahman so how can he meditates on other brahman. But the translation is totally valid it seems ur claim is only invalid here. paraṃ hi brahma kathitaṃ yogayuktena tanmayā। It totally means I was in yogic connection with Brahmana. Yoga obviously means meditation and yukti means connection with universal spirit. So, ur translation is not following Sanskrit grammer but kmg's dies so how come its even valid.

Comment: As for contradiction also its not contradicting anything.Whereas ur claim is contradicting shrutis so its in-sense wrong translation and so is invalid. Sathapatha Brahman describes how Narayana became Brahmana.Shruti describes those who knows brahman becomes brahman themselves.So, yes Krishna is Brahman and so are we. We just dont realise it so we say, om tat sat. And yes there is no diff between avtars and avtaris and as per as shrutis we are all forms of brahman. So ur claim is not following rules thats why is invalid itself. thsts what i shared before that we r all brahmans. Aham Brahmasmi.

Comment: As for why he should meditate on other Brahman its because everyone should meditate on their inner self (Brahman). Padma Puran and Kurma Puran and Even Mahabharata states that Lord Vishnu (Krishna) always remains in a yogic connection with Lord Shiva. Even that was one of the boons asked by Lord Krishna from Lord Shiva to remain always close and connected to him. As Saguna always meditates on Nirguna. So, Even The Tridevs viz Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesha always meditates on their Nirguna selfs as the source of their origin itself.

Comment: I hope this clarifies your queries. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am answering my own question because I got some new proofs to validate the point of my own question.

In the above verse It is said that no one but just Lord kala controls maa Lakshmi.

It's gonna be a bit long so just read till the last.

So what and who is kaala.? Where in sanskrit kala has 3 meanings - time, death and black (space) so lord shiva is also the lord of time and space and death. So Lord Shiva as Mahakaala is the Lord of Time, Death and Space himself. They areca fragments of him.

Here is the quote from chapter six of Shiva Gita.

> “prāṇaḥ kālastathā mṛtyuramṛtaṁ bhūtamapyahama | bhavyaṁ bhaviṣyatkṛtsnaṁ ca viśvaṁ sarvātmakō’pyahama |” (Shiva Gita 6:26)
>
> **“I’m the Prana (life force), I’m the time, death, and eternity. I’m the past, present and future. I’m everything indeed!”**

So from above verses it is proved that lord shiva is the lord of time, death and space(eternity). (For more on Kala I have given in question only after editing way back, see that).

According to Ishwara Gita Chapter 4.:

> अहं हि सर्वशक्तीनां प्रवर्त्तकनिवर्त्तकः ।
> आधारभूतः सर्वासां निधानममृतस्य च ॥ ४.२०॥
> Meaning: - know me alone to be enforcer as well as withdrawer of all the potency, besides being support of all (potencies) I am the abode of immortality in the form of nectar.

> एका सर्वान्तरा शक्तिः करोति विविधं जगत् ।
> आस्थाय ब्रह्माणो रूपं मन्मयी मदधिष्ठिता ॥ ४.२१॥
> Meaning: - One of my potency, established in me and formulation of mine, situated in innerself of all beings, assumes the form of four-faced Bramha and creates various types of worlds.
>
> अन्या च शक्तिर्विपुला संस्थापयति मे जगत् ।
> भूत्वा नारायणोऽनन्तो जगन्नाथो जगन्मयः ॥ ४.२२॥
> Meaning: - My other potency, known as Anant (Infinite), Jagganath (Lord of Universe), assumes the form of Narayana for nurturing and sustaining the worlds.
>
> तृतीया महती शक्तिर्निहन्ति सकलं जगत् ।
> तामसी मे समाख्याता कालाख्या रुद्ररूपिणी ॥ ४.२३॥
> Meaning: - My third potency, **which is formation of Rudra, by the name of Kala,** is tamasi and it annihilates the entire creation
>
> पश्याम्यशेषमेवेदं वर्त्तमानं स्वभावतः ।
> करोति कालो भगवान् महायोगेश्वरः स्वयम् ॥ ४.२९॥
> Meaning: - Restrained to my own nature, I am witness of entire world. **Mahayogeshwar Bhagawaan Kala** creates the entire Creation.
>
> योगः सम्प्रोच्यते योगी मायी शास्त्रेषु सूरिभिः ।
> योगेश्वरोऽसौ भगवान् महादेवो महान् प्रभुः ॥ ४.३०॥
> Meaning: - who is refered as Yoga, Yogi and Maya by people well-versed in scriptures, is none other than **Maha-Yogeshwar Lord Mahadeva.**

So According to Lord Shiva himself Brahma is his Rajasik form, Narayan is his Sattvik form and Kala is his Tamasik form.

As for Lord Shiva he is Nirguna.

Lord Krishna said about Lord Siva in  the Anusashana Parva :

> "namo 'stu te śāśvatasarvayone; brahmādhipaṃ tvām ṛṣayo vadanti
> **tapaś ca sattvaṃ ca rajas; tamaś ca tvām eva satyaṃ ca vadanti santaḥ"**(MBH 13:15:30)

> The blessed Krishna said, 'I saluted Mahadeva, saying,--Salutations to thee, O thou that art the eternal origin of all things. The Rishis say that thou art the Lord of the Vedas. The righteous say that thou art Penance, **thou art Sattwa, thou art Rajas, thou art Tamas, and thou art Truth**

So, Krishna has opined along with Great Sages that Lord Siva is NOT only the abode of the Tamas quality, He is the abode of the Sattwas, the Rajas and the Tamas quality.

Further Vedas says that Lord Shiva is beyond all 3 gunas and is Nirgun Brahman.:

> "Maheshwara (Great Lord) who is Black and yellow rules with Avidya, Maya or Mula-Prakriti is Red(rajas)-White (sattvam)-& black(tamas) & that is co-existed with him [Shandilya Upanishad 3:01]

As for Puranas being sattvik, rajasik and tamasik totally contradicts Mahabharata and bhagwat gita itself. These are all just sectatarian nonsense and nothing else. See [this](https://harivallabha.blogspot.com/2018/06/classification-of-puranas.html?m=1) site it explains everything with proofs from mahabharata and vedas.

Now, As for the finale.

Do Lord Shiva really controls maa Lakshmi or is it just time. Though I have proved the time is Lord Shiva only. Plus here both creater and ordainer are mentioned so the 3rd will only be destroyer (kala/time/death). But still people have confusions regarding this so I am giving a direct verse which is said by Lord Shiva only to prove my point and yes it's Lord Shiva only who controls Maa Lakshmi and no one else.

Ishwar Gita Chapter 6.:

> योऽपि नारायणोऽनन्तो लोकानां प्रभवाव्ययः ।
> ममैव परमा मूर्तिः करोति परिपालनम् ॥ ६.१४॥
> Meaning: - The endless Narayana, origin of world(s), is my (Lord Shiva's) best form and by my blessings he sustains entire creation.
>
> या च श्रीः सर्वभूतानां ददाति विपुलां श्रियम् ।
> पत्नी नारायणस्यासौ वर्त्तते मदनुग्रहात् ॥ ६.३१॥
> **Meaning: - The goddess of wealth and dispenser of the same, who is the consort of Narayana, known as “Sri” also functions at my (Lord Shiva's) command alone.**

Further, [Mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826410.html) also says that **Mahadeva is the possessor of ‘Sri’** and is identical with the deity of blazing flames viz. Agni (the cosmic Agni-Linga is the reference).

> “dyaurnabhaḥ pṛthivī khaṁ ca tathā caivaiṣa bhūpatiḥ |
>
> sarvavidyēśvaraḥ śrīmānēṣa cāpi vibhāvasuḥ ||” (MBH 13:85:93)
>
> “He (Mahadeva) is Heaven, Firmament, Earth, and the Welkin. He is called the Lord of the Earth. He is the Lord whose sway is owned by all obstacles. **He is endued with ‘Sri’** and He is identical with the deity of blazing flames”.

So, from the above verse it's fully crystal clear that it's Lord Shiva only who controls Maa Lakshmi alone. So, mahabharata is also in sync with it. So, I hope it's clear to everyone now and 2 reliable sources when compliments each other are always right. Period. .

Comment: Please, Be respectful to your fellow users!

Comment: Ishwar gita never heard off.. best pramanas accepted are bhagavad gita, vedas and upanishad

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49902/20968

Comment: @PrasannaR Just because we haven't heard of some scripture, we shouldn't say "best" is A B or C scriptures.

Comment: Ishwara Gita is the original Bhagwata Gita so is the best pramana. U must have never heard of b.g. or understand its essence also. Rest is just name sake.

Comment: Our scriptures says people gets what they deserve bcz of their karma. Prd..

Answer (score 11):

**Why Maa Lakshmi says that neither Lord Brahma nor Lord Vishnu only Lord Shiva commands her to move from one place to another.?**

This is the interpretation of [mahapashupatastra blog](http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/2014/11/the-unfading-glory-of-mahakala.html) for the below Sanskrit verse:

> न धाता न विधाता मां विदधाति कथं चन
>
> **काल**स तु शक्र पर्यायान मैनं शक्रावमन्यथाः
>
> śrīruvāca nō dhātā na vidhātā mā̃ vidadhāti kathañcana.
>
> **kāla**stu śakra paryāgānmainaṁ śakrāvamanyathāḥ|

Kala (kāla) doesn't mean Shiva always, see the [alternate translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b052.htm):

> "Sree said, 'Neither the Creator nor the Ordainer rules me. It is **Time** that moves me from one place to another. Do not, O Sakra, disregard Vali.'

In the [next chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b054.htm), Kala is described in details, providing few verses here:

> It is Time that is the mover of all beings that move. It is Time that destroys all beings.
>
> Every one is assailed here by Time. Nothing among beings that are subtile or gross enjoys an immunity from Time's sway. All things are being cooked in Time's cauldron. Time has no master.

So, here Kala is used to denote the Brahman (the Ultimate Reality) which is Vishnu in Vaishnavism. This will be clear form below verses from Mahabharata, Bhagavata Gita and Vishnu Purana etc.

---

In [Shrimadbhagvadgita 11.32](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=11&field_nsutra_value=32&etsiva=1&etgb=1&setgb=1),

> श्री भगवानुवाच
>
> **कालोऽस्मि** लोकक्षयकृत्प्रवृद्धो...
>
> The Blessed Lord [Krishna] said I am the full-grown world-destroying Time...

---

[Vishnu Purana: Part I: Chapter II](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp036.htm):

> These four--Pradhána (primary or crude matter), Purusha (spirit), Vyakta (visible substance), and **Kála** (time)--the wise consider to be the pure and supreme condition of **Vishńu**.
>
> The two forms which are other than the essence of unmodified **Vishńu**, are Pradhána (matter) and Purusha (spirit); and his other form, by which those two are connected or separated, is called **Kála** (time).

---

Also, the below verses of **Chapter 5th of Kurma Purana** (mentioned in [What is the Life span of Hindu gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/what-is-the-life-span-of-hindu-gods/23603#23603) answer) describe Kala as creator and destroyer of even Trinity gods: Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva:

> 21. It is said that in due course of time, Brahma, Narayana and Isa (Rudra), all the three, become merged in Prakrti and their
>     remanifestation also is to take place.
> 22. Thus, Brahma, the elements (or all living beings)and even Vasudeva and Sankara are created by Kala (time). He alone devours them again.
> 23. This Lord Kala is beginningless, endless, free from old age or decay and immortal. He is the Supreme Ruler because of his
>     omnipresence, independence and his state of being the soul of all.
> 24. There have been many Brahmas, Rudras, Narayanas and others, but there is one Lord controller of all viz. Kala. He is omniscient. So
>     states the Śruti (Vedas).

---

On a side note, mahapashupatastra blog and narayanastra blog tries to prove supremacy of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu respectively so their interpretation would be towards that direction, see below pages for more details:

- http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/a-criticism-of-naraya%e1%b9%87astra-blog
- https://narayanastra.blogspot.com/2015/02/we-have-noticed-that-our-poor-comrade.html

Answer (score 3):

> Why Maa Lakshmi says that neither Lord Brahma nor Lord Vishnu only Lord Shiva commands her to move from one place to another.?

She didn't. If translated this way, it would be a tamasic section of the Mahabharata since it contradicts the Vedas. In the Vedas, the Purusha Sukta says:

> "Hri and Sri (Lakshmi) are your (Vishnu's) wives".

So, Lakshmi will only listen to her husband Vishnu, and not Shiva, Brahma, or anyone else.

As a matter of fact, the translation is not correct. Why is Dhata being translated as Brahma, Vidhata as Vishnu, and Kala as Shiva? Kala just means time. So it just means, "only time controls me". Given the context of the section and its purpose to explain time, the verse is just an illustration meant to explain the nature of time.

Comment: Verse number please for this: *"Hri and Sri (Lakshmi) are your (Vishnu's) wives".*

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The 7th to the last verse of the purusha sukta of the krishna yajur veda, as follows: ह्रीश्च ते लक्ष्मीश्च पत्न्यौ

Comment: @Ikshvaku but does Vidhata mean Vishnu?

Comment: @user22253 vidhata means controller, dhata means creator!

Comment: I think you should be less emotional and more realistic before answering in such a commanding way dear sir!. I suggest you to read this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50832/24265 where perfectly the logical stance is made..

Answer (score 2):

Goddess Lakṣmī is said to be Cañcalā (चञ्चला/चंचला) by her own nature, i.e. always moving/unsteady. This is especially true when we see her as the personified form of riches, fortune, and wealth.

In that sense, it is most apt that the reference to "Kāla" is in the general sense of "time", and not any deity.

This proposition is further in consonance with the curse pronounced on goddess Lakṣmī by goddess Sarasvatī, in the Skanda Purāṇa Verse 7.1.165.(100-102)

> [Chapter 165](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626953.html) - Greatness of Sāvitrī, Prabhāsa-kṣetra-māhātmya,
> Prabhāsakhaṇḍa
>
> यस्मान्मां संपरित्यज्य गतास्ता देवयोषितः ।
>  तासामपि तथा शापं प्रदास्ये
> कुपिता भृशम् ॥ १०० ॥
>
> > 100. “Since these Deva-damsels have gone away leaving me alone, I am very angry. I shall curse them too.”
>
> नैकत्र वासो लक्ष्म्यास्तु भविष्यति कदाचन ।
>  रुद्रापि **चंचला**
> तावन्मूर्खेषु च वसिष्यसि ॥ १०१ ॥
>
> म्लेच्छेषु पर्वतीयेषु कुत्सिते कुष्ठिते तथा ।
>  वाचाटे चावलिप्ते च
> अभिशस्ते दुरात्मनि ।
>  एवंविधे नरे तुभ्यं वसतिः शापकारिता ॥ १०२ ॥
>
> > 101. “**Lakṣmī will never stay permanently in one place. Even if restrained, she will be very fickle and abide in houses of fools**”.
>
> > 102. O Lakṣmī, by my curse I have restricted your residence to these persons: barbarians, mountain-dwellers, despicable ones, lepers,
> >      the talkative, the arrogant, the accursed, the wicked, and persons of
> >      similar features.”

Therefore when in the Mahabharata, Lakṣmī says -

> "*Neither the Creator(Brahma) nor the Ordainer(Vishnu) rules me. It is Kāla that moves me from one place to another.*"

It isn't a reference to any deity.

##### The Kāla must be known as the general nature of Time, which changes everything. Kāla is not a reference to god Śiva.

I discuss the allegorical nature of time in [this Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50670/17833).

If at all, Lakṣmī were to obey the command of anyone, that'd be her own husband i.e., Viṣṇu, which is what all dharma-śāstras teach - "*that a wife must obey her husband, and not other's husband*"

Although she's a great goddess, she's under no one's control, she controls everything (at least as per the Vaiṣṇava theology).