Does any canonical scripture say that the Mahabharata has "Tamasic sections"?
Not looking for sectarian writings from the medieval times onwards which have notions like the Ganga not being sacred because she spent time lodged in Siva's locks.
In this
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44700/12489
answer, a user writes,

She didn't. If translated this way, it would be a tamasic section of the Mahabharata since it contradicts the Vedas.

Is this supported by scripture - the notion that the Mahabharata has "Tamasic sections"?
On the surface it doesn't look like something any canonical scripture from Aryaavarta would say.
